# Wireless suddenly dropping with a Ralink RT2870

Tags: wireless, 12.04, ralink

I have a **Linksys WUSB600N** v1 Dual-Band Wireless-N Network Adapter `Ralink RT2870` USB dongle that worked flawlessly in 11.10.  Since upgrading, I can't keep a connection for more than five minutes.  The wild world of Google was unable to provide a solution, and I would rather not downgrade although that remains a possibility.

Results of syslog:

```
slack@slack:~$ tail /var/log/syslog
Apr 26 20:26:10 slack AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Apr 26 20:26:10 slack AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
Apr 26 20:26:10 slack dbus[972]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Apr 26 20:26:10 slack AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Initializing PackageKit transaction
Apr 26 20:26:10 slack AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/aaed4e38eb3c41ad86d2bab6ca03ee7c
Apr 26 20:26:10 slack AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/aaed4e38eb3c41ad86d2bab6ca03ee7c
Apr 26 20:26:12 slack dbus[972]: [system] Activating service name='com.ubuntu.SystemService' (using servicehelper)
Apr 26 20:26:12 slack dbus[972]: [system] Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.SystemService'
Apr 26 20:30:26 slack AptDaemon.PackageKit: INFO: Get updates()
Apr 26 20:30:27 slack AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Finished transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/aaed4e38eb3c41ad86d2bab6ca03ee7c
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Connect to your wireless, wait 5 minutes and after it drops the connection paste the output of `tail /var/log/syslog/` [on this page: Fixee](http://fixee.org) and paste the link by editing your question.

Comment: I was running apt-get update and it stops fetching, and I can't access any websites although network manager indicates that I'm still connected

Comment: **Do just this things please:** Connect to your wireless, wait 5 minutes and after it drops the connection paste the output of `tail /var/log/syslog/` (type it in the terminal of course) on this page: [Fixee](http://fixee.org) and paste the link by editing your question.

Comment: It doesn't seem to drop unless I'm using it heavily.  It generally lets me browse the net, but if I try to torrent or run apt it will drop, but I only know this because all activity ceases, not because  network manager lets me know.  It did not disconnect in the ten minutes I let it idle, but did so soon after I tried using it.  This makes it difficult to post the output of syslog according to your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that the official rt2870usb kernel driver is not reliable.

I just downloaded the 2.5.0.3 driver from ralink and compiled it. That works flawlessly.

Comment: the only drivers 2-5-0-3 are not for RT2870 on the site See http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501 RT5572 USB 03/22/2012 v2.6.0.0 RT8070 /RT3070 /RT3370 /RT5370 /RT5372 USB 03/28/2012 2.5.0.3 RT539x PCIe 09/26/2011 2.5.0.3 RT3572USB 04/27/2011 2.5.0.0 Where did you download from?